# Graph bipartite?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, bipartite-graphs

Is this graph bipartite('quadpartite') ?

[image: a graph with levels]

I think it is, when every tree is bipartite and this is similar, but im not sure.

Comment: Yes, it’s bipartite. If the layers of vertices are numbered $0,1,2,3,4$ from left to right, one part consists of layers $0,2$, and $4$, and the other of layers $1$ and $3$. All edges are between vertices in layers of opposite parity. (It is not a tree, however, as it has cycles.)

Comment: One characterization of *bipartite* is that there are no odd length cycles.

Comment: Thank you for explanation.